# All in one Declarations in New Objects (Streamlined)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, object

I'm using c#, I know you can streamline the creation of new objects

```
List<String> myStrings = new List<String>() { "Hello", "GoodBye" };
```

I also use it for creating new treenodes

```
node_Clicked.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Text = "New Node" });
```

Pretty useful, however, I would like to use it for list views however when i start writing it:

```
folder_listView.Items.Add(
    new ListViewItem() 
    { 
        Text = "First Col", 
        SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() 
        { 
            Text = "Second Col" 
        }),
```

I get Intellisense error:

Invalid initializer member declarator

So I guess that means you can't instantiate objects within newly instantiated objects because not all the objects (such as lists) inside the newly instantiated object have been instantiated?

Am I right in thinking that?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the problem is `SubItems.Add()` is a *method*, not a property/field. Calling a method is very different from initializing a member!

That said, you *would* be able to do `SubItems = ...` if it were settable, but as @RB pointed out, it is not.

Comment: For reference, it's not settable, so he can't ;)

Comment: Or if it doesn't have a setter, if `Items` has an `AddRange` method, then you can instantiate/initialize a `ListViewItem` collection, then pass those in via `AddRange` (or settle for a loop calling `Add`; perhaps as an extension method)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes, and `AddRange` could take an inline-instantiated object, but it would still have to be a separate call.

Comment: @lc. yeah, but what else are you going to do?  You could nest it all in one method chain: `listview.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]{ ... all my items ...})`

Comment: Thanks everyone, really useful information. I have just separated it out for this just this once ;-) just thought it would be really useful streamlining it!

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Of course nothing else. I was just clarifying for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As lc. pointed out, `ListViewItemCollection.Add` and `ListViewSubItemCollection.Add` are methods and thus not part of the normal object/collection initializer syntax.  As it doesn't expose a setter, you can just instantiate a new item that way.  However, you can take advantage of its `AddRange` method, and you can shift construction of the subitem to a method as there isn't an appropriate constructor overload for you:

```
public ListView folder_listView = new ListView();

public void Build()
{
    folder_listView.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]
    {
        Item("First Col", 
            new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(){ Text = "Second Col" }
            ),
        Item("Another col", 
            new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(){ Text = "Another Second Col" }, 
            new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(){ Text = "Another Third Col" }
            )
    });
}

private static ListViewItem Item(string text, params ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(text);
    item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
    return item;
}
```

This is just an example; feel free to build any kind of helper API that you wish to help you manage what properties of the items/subitems you're building.